# Import succeeds in interpreter and fails in script (same Python executable) "No module named `src`"

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-importlib

I have a program designed to automatically parse code in a repository and create an API based on a specification. Parsing the code requires using `importlib` to import the code I'm going to parse. The line where things diverge as mentioned in the title is `spec = importlib.util.find_spec(modulename, package='package_name')`; in the interpreter, it works perfectly. I can even import the function that calls this function from the script, and that works too.

The target repository that is being operated on has the structure

```
__init__.py
setup.py
src (directory containing all Python files including an __init__.py)
```

where `setup.py` looks like

```
setuptools.setup(name='package_name',
                 version='0.1',
                 author='Me',
                 description='For doing secret corporate stuff',
                 packages=['package_name'],
                 package_dir={'package_name': 'src'},
                 package_data={'package_name': ['file1',
                                                'file2']},
                 install_requires=['various', 'stuff'])
```

I'm definitely using the same Python in both cases. I'm not installing the repository as a package but rather cloning it and attempting to operate on it from the root directory. On multiple computers, I'm able to import `src` and `src.module` for each `module` in the `src` directory in the interpreter, but cannot do it from a script.

Comment: My very, very ugly, hopefuily temporary hack: `screen -dm ipython -i script.py`; add `os._exit(9)` to the end of the script; run another script that waits for the (now asynchronous) script to write a small text file before continuing with the main execution.

Comment: Your project directory structure seems problematic to me. Lots of red flags. I recommend you check this tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: Restructuring my package directory to have the `ctha_ontologies` directory under `src` did not help with the ImportError.

Comment: Do you really want to import `src`? Usually that is not what one wants to do. Maybe rewrite the question with the updated project directory structure, even though I am not sure that is relevant to your actual issue, but since you added it to the question...

Comment: I am really not sure what it is you are trying to do. Are you trying to import your own package with `importlib`? Or a different package? Maybe we need a [mre].

Comment: I will try to create a MRE at some point soon. I can't share the code as written because my company owns it, not me. The purpose of the software is to create an API inside a Docker container based on a small specification file, code documentation, and type hints. Not all repositories are structured as packages, so I prefer to have a one-size-fits-all solution that works from the root directory of the repository rather than relying on a `pip install` (which is very hard to execute, because repositories can depend on private repositories requiring deploy keys), hence why I'm importing `src`.

Comment: I'm working on my own repository, but really I want a solution that will work on as arbitrary of a repository as possible.

Comment: It appears that all I had to do to get the script to work is `sys.path.append(repository_directory)`.